# How to connect to another computer through the Internet using ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have `Ubuntu 13.10` on my **laptop** which I would like to use to connect to my `Ubuntu 12.04` **desktop**. I installed the **open ssh server** on the desktop machine using:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I checked that the server is running:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

and I get:

```
start: Job is already running: ssh
```

Next I checked if there is a firewall using:

```
sudo ufw status
```

and I get:

```
Status: inactive
```

Next I found out the **desktop's IP address** by executing:

```
ip addr | grep inet
```

and I get:

```
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
inet 193.51.236.62/24 brd 193.51.236.255 scope global eth0
inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe10:e8da/64 scope link
```

So I suppose that **193.51.236.62** is my IP address.

Then on my laptop I verify that **193.51.236.62** is pingable and then I do:

```
ssh -v martin@193.51.236.62
```

and I get:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 193.51.236.62 [193.51.236.62] port 22.
```

And nothing else seems to be happening. Please, how can I troubleshoot this problem? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I can safely ping the server machine:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ ping -c3 193.51.236.62
PING 193.51.236.62 (193.51.236.62) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 193.51.236.62: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=2.82 ms
64 bytes from 193.51.236.62: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=4.05 ms
64 bytes from 193.51.236.62: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=4.08 ms

--- 193.51.236.62 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.823/3.653/4.082/0.587 ms
```

**EDIT2:**

I tried to diagnose the connection using `nmap` as suggested:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ nmap 193.51.236.62

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-31 18:39 CET
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
```

and then:

```
martin@martin-Studio-1537:~$ nmap -Pn 193.51.236.62

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-01-31 18:40 CET
Nmap scan report for 193-51-236-62.lille.inria.fr (193.51.236.62)
Host is up (0.0056s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3128/tcp open  squid-http
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.18 seconds
```

Comment: Have you install OpenSSH on the server? Does the server has a firewall which blocks SSH in some way?

Comment: @OrangeTux Yes, I installed `openssh-server` on *both* computers

Comment: Can you ping to the server?

Comment: @OrangeTux Yes, I edited my answer to include the results of a ping

Comment: If this a public server, **don't** turn off the firewall *(and boradcast the IP address AND the login, **VERY** bad idea...)*... Just allow SSH through on [port 22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_well-known_ports_%28computing%29#Well-known_ports), it should do that anyway, if you configure it. Then try just `ssh martin@193.51.236.62`.

Comment: @wilf Thank you! I enabled the firewall. Do you mean broadcast as in broadcast on this forum?

Answer (score 4):

Start by checking to see that you can ssh into the desktop *from the desktop*.

`ssh 127.0.0.1`

If that works, I would check to see if the outside IP and internal IP are different.

Comment: I tried it and I get: `The authenticity of host '127.0.0.1' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is ... Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? `

Comment: There is a answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/392213/178596) on finding the IP address of a machine by the way.

Comment: That's good. That means the SSH server is running. You can safely say yes, and it should connect.

Comment: @wilf I tried it. The external and local IP address are the same and they equal the address that I posted.

Comment: Which you shouldn't post, as it is an external IP...

Comment: If both computers are on different networks (different external IPs ), is it possible that there is some ISP/modem-level filtering that blocks port 22, but allows ICMP pings?

Comment: @saiarcot895 I am sorry, but I have no idea. I activated the firewall as @wilf suggested and when I hit `ufw status` I see that the port 22 is allowed.

Comment: Aye, could be... proxys are are a possibility as well. With problems like this, I generally just `nmap` it: `nmap 193.51.236.62` - that will show the open ports as well.

Comment: @wilf I edited my question to post the results of `nmap`. How can I interpret them? What can cause 22 to be absent?

Comment: If it was open, and running ssh, it would show as `22/tcp open  ssh`. If it has ssh, but is closed: `22/tcp closed  ssh`. As @saiarcot895 says, it could be the router/modem or the Internet Service Provider filtering the ports. A proxy or two may also prevent it working.

Comment: I'm starting to also suspect a different firewall on the desktop computer that's only allowing 8080 and 3128.