# Connecting to remote SQL Server database over SSH

Tags: 16.04, ssh, mssql

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL Server over SSH.

How can I do this via the terminal?

Comment: ssh is the command to initiate a Ssh connection..  e.g. ssh remotehost mysql would attempt to connect to host 'remotest' and run the command 'mysql' as your current user.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running on your local computer? Which version of Ubuntu are you running on the SQL server?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Internet through a remote server via SSH connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053453/how-to-connect-to-internet-through-a-remote-server-via-ssh-connection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to another computer through the Internet using ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413650/how-to-connect-to-another-computer-through-the-internet-using-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

First connect to remote server using ssh tunnelling

ssh @

and once you are connected to remote server you can access mysql using
mysql -h  -u  -p